# Install a python package in a virtual environment directly from git

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

I have a python package I want to use, but it appears that the version installed through pip is seriously outdated, to the point where example code doesn't work.  some research independently verified that in order to get the code to work properly, I need the latest version from git.

How do I install a python package from within a virtual environment directly from git without going through pip?

Alternatively, since I don't know too much about pip, if this should never be necessary, then how do I force pip to install the latest version on github?

Comment: Why **not** use pip?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, hence my last paragraph.  I did not know if pip could do that, and I didn't immediately think that it could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to reference [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) documentation.

Here's the basic format:

```
pip install -e vcs+protocol://repo_url/#egg=pkg&subdirectory=pkg_dir
```

In the case of git it'd be something like

```
pip install -e git+https://www.github.com/name_your_project/name_your_repo
```

Comment: how do we freeze those into requirements.txt?